# javascript html select add optgroup and option dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

let say i have a `<select id="chat" size="9" />` , i want to add some optgroup and option which will be like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP4E9/

with object like this

```
{friendchat:[{name:"somefriend1",...},{name:"somefriend2",...},
otherchat:[{name:"someother1",...},{name:"someother2",...},
friendrequest:[{name:"somerequest1",...},{name:"somerequest2",...},
sentrequest:[{name:"somesent1",...},{name:"somesent2",...}]
```

edit: typed input instead of select...

Comment: I think you mean `<select>` and `<option>`?

Comment: For one, <optgroup> goes with <select>, not <input />. And most importantly, your question isn't very clear. Don't only give examples; word your problem.

Comment: i dont know how to adding <option> into <optgroup> and adding <optgroup> to <select> dynamically, i have searched for it and it doesn't help much

Comment: 動態產生下拉式選項群組功能(html select add optgroup and option dynamically) https://jsfiddle.net/trz5gefh/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/9n408evd/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, how about jQuery ?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP4E9/2/

```
var opt = {
    friendchat:[
        {name:"somefriend1"},
        {name:"somefriend2"}
    ],
    otherchat:[
        {name:"someother1"},
        {name:"someother2"}
    ],
    friendrequest:[
        {name:"somerequest1"},
        {name:"somerequest2"}
    ],
    sentrequest:[
        {name:"somesent1"},
        {name:"somesent2"}
    ]
};

$(function(){
    var $select = $('#mySelect');
    $.each(opt, function(key, value){
        var group = $('<optgroup label="' + key + '" />');
        $.each(value, function(){
            $('<option />').html(this.name).appendTo(group);
        });
        group.appendTo($select);
    });
});
```

Comment: Great solution! Tks!

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>***[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/67ee6/)***</kbd>

You could (need to) use:

- `document.createElement()`

  - Create elements by type. For example *option* or *select*.
- `element.appendChild()`

  - Add created element to another.
- `element.textContent`, or `element.innerHTML` or `element.innerText`

  - Set text value.

Having the options object:

```js
    var opt = {
        friendchat:[
            {name:"somefriend1"},
            {name:"somefriend2"}
        ],
        otherchat:[
            {name:"someother1"},
            {name:"someother2"}
        ],
        friendrequest:[
            {name:"somerequest1"},
            {name:"somerequest2"}
        ],
        sentrequest:[
            {name:"somesent1"},
            {name:"somesent2"}
        ]
    };
```

A wrapper to put the select into:

```html
    <div id="wrap_sel"></div>
```

We can add by for example:

```js
    /* Build option group.
     * @sel : Select element to add group to.
     * @lab : Label for option group.
     * @opts: Options Array.
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    function add_optgr(sel, lab, opts) {
        var i, 
            len = opts.length, opt,
            gr = document.createElement('OPTGROUP');
        
        gr.label = lab;
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
            opt.textContent = opts[i].name;
            // Here you most likely also want to set .value
            // opt.value = opts[i].value;
            gr.appendChild(opt);
        }
        sel.appendChild(gr);
        return gr;
    }

    /* Build the select.
     * @wrap: Container where to add finished product.
     * @size: Size attribute for select.
     * @opt : Options object.
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    function build_select(wrap, size, opt) {
        var sel = document.createElement('SELECT'),
            prop;
        size = size || 1;
        sel.size = size;
        for (prop in opt)
            if (opt.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                add_optgr(sel, prop, opt[prop]);
        wrap.appendChild(sel);
    }

    /* On DOM ready, build the select. */
    build_select(
        document.getElementById('wrap_sel'),
        9,
        opt
    );
```

As commented in code, you would likely want to have a value for the options as well. Giving you options object structure something like:

```js
    var opt = {
        friendchat:[
            {name: "Some Friend 1", value: "friend1"},
            {name: "Some Friend 2", value: "friend2"}
        ],
        ...
    };
```

Comment: Glad to see "non" jQuery solutions still exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is for empty default select options and add new

```
var select_option = '';
for (i=0; i<response.length; i++){
options += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
}    

$('.selectclassname').html('').append(select_option)
```