# How to Set optgroup value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var newOptGroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
newOptGroup.label = 'Indian cars';
newOptGroup.value = '103';
newOptGroup.appendChild(option);
```

How can i set optgroup value in JavaScript.?Here 'newOptGroup.label = 'Indian Cars' is working, but 'newOptGroup.value ='103' is not working.

Comment: What is parent here?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: did u check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266171/javascript-html-select-add-optgroup-and-option-dynamically

Comment: optgroups have no value property

Answer (score 0):

According to w3[0] 'optgroup' does not feature 'value' properties.
So..essentially you can not assign it. When using a 'select', you do not select the 'optgroup' itself, but an 'option' element - with possibly a 'value' - inside the 'optgroup'

[0] http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/optgroup.html